# How to use Flask with mysql (without sqlalchemy - raw sql query)?

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask framework. How to use Flask with mysql (without sqlalchemy - raw sql query)?

Here is example from official tutorial, how to configure it to use mysql?

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash


# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)

# Load default config and override config from an environment variable
app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE='/tmp/firma.db',
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='development key',
    USERNAME='admin',
    PASSWORD='default'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FIRMA_SETTINGS', silent=True)


def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv


def init_db():
    """Creates the database tables."""
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('firma.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()


@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
...
```

How to configure it to use mysql?

Comment: try with this [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb)

Comment: Any reason you aren't using sqlite3?  It is very easy to execute raw sql without models.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.techillumination.in/2014/01/python-web-application-development.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a mysql driver.  Python doesn't come with one by default.  You'll have to install a 3rd party library like [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/).  Even if you use an ORM like sqlalchemy, you'll still need to install the driver.  Also, you can run raw SQL with sqlalchemy.

Comment: Is it ok to run raw SQL queries from within flask?I have read that SQL injection has it's own drawbacks in terms of security.

Comment: @NSP There's nothing wrong with running raw SQL on the server side.  The problem comes when you start using user input as part of your SQL requests.  The popular ORM libraries have a lot of safeguards when constructing queries that you don't get if you're just building raw sql strings yourself.